# Как реализовать удаление поста на <div> RedBean PHP AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, redbeanphp

**Здравствуйте**. Есть у меня функция создания постов пользователем, теперь мне надо реализовать удаление поста, но проблема в том, что я не могу этого сделать так как не знаю, как можно это реализовать при нажатии просто на определенный `div` к примеру с `id="post_delete_btn"` или `name="post_delete"`. Ну и + желательно с ajax (но там я сам разберусь, главное что-бы вы показали мне, как сделать функцию на php, которая будет работать при нажатии на мой `div`.

Вот пример того, что бы я хотел (но это пример не работает!!!)

**Разметка:**

```
<button id="post_delete_btn" name="post_delete" style="background-color: #b831ff; color: #fff;">
    Удалить пост
</button>';
```

**ajax-script.php (тут должно быть удаление поста к примеру под номером 77):**

```
if ($data['post_delete']) {
    $post_del = R::load('posts', 77);
    R::trash($post_del);
}
```

**AJAX:**

```
$('#post_delete_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax-script',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('#post_delete_btn').serialize(),
        success: function(){
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение проблемы через 10 минут после отправки этого вопроса (простите за внимание).
Оказывается можно было просто написать в ajax-script.php так:

```
$post_del = R::load('posts', 77);
R::trash($post_del);
```

То есть без `if ($data['post_delete'])`